# Applying Jackson annotations on Groovy / Grails / GORM properties to getters instead of fields

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, jackson, grails-orm

I'm attempting to use Jackson annotations with Groovy / Grails / GORM.

Annotations applied to a Groovy property are applied to its field, not its getter.

GORM lazy loads relationship properties by default. Lazy properties have the appropriate default value (null, 0, false, etc.) until the object is loaded. Field access doesn't cause GORM to load the object; only getter access causes an unloaded object to be loaded.

Thus, for Jackson to support lazy loaded GORM object, Jackson annotations must be applied to property getters instead of fields.

I do not want to have to set lazy: false for all my relationships, nor do I want to have to write an explicit getter for each property so that I can annotate the getter instead of the property.

Is there:

1. a way in Groovy / Grails / GORM to associate a property annotation with its getter instead of its field
2. a way in Jackson to setup access through the corresponding getter and/or setter when only annotating the field
3. an annotation processor to move annotations from a field to its corresponding getter and/or setter (I started to write one, but noticed many potential problems with this that might take a while to solve, so I'd prefer some solution other than one I have to write myself)
4. some other solution

Comment: sounds like this is primarily about lazy loading? check https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted. If you answer, then I'll check your answer as correct. Thanks for the help.